# Is Adobe AIR exporting a flash file to the phone?

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

If I develop a mobile app in flash using AIR is it exporting as flash or is it converting? I know this is a really stupid question so I apologise in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think so... since last versions of android don't support flash technology natively. You can check http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html. They say that the exported file is an APK.

Answer (score 1):

Is AIR exporting as flash? Well... Yes, and no.

On Android exported `.apk` consists of platform specific glue code (for startup and platform communication, along with any native extensions), and Flash files (regular SWFs) either linked to installed AIR runtime, or with captive runtime (basically Flash player bundled with the `.apk`). The bundled SWF is more or less the same as on other platform.

On iOS, `.ipa` file consists or ARM recompiled Actionscript code (since Apple doesn't allow interpreted code in apps), and SWFs which contain graphics and other data.